# Smart contract: How to get return of Solidity function in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, solidity

I would like to get the return of my function in React but I don't know why it's not working (I get always in my console `undefined` when I try `console.log(this.state.data)`:

Method in my contract.sol:

```
function data() public view returns (uint256){
        return choice1;
}
```

app.js :

```
class Pool1 extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
          web3: '',
          data: ''
        }

        this.getCote = this.getCote.bind(this);
      }

 getCote(web3){
        //Get the contract
        const contract = require('truffle-contract');
        const Betting = contract(BettingContract);
        Betting.setProvider(web3.currentProvider);
        var BettingInstance;
        web3.eth.getAccounts((error, accounts) => {
        Betting.deployed().then((instance) => {
    //Instantiate the contract in a promise
          BettingInstance = instance
    }).then((result) => {
          //Calling the AmountOne function of the smart-contract
          return BettingInstance.data.call({from: accounts[0]})
        }).then((result) => {
          this.setState({
            data : result.c 
          })
        });
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `methods` [in your call](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call)

```js
return BettingInstance.methods.data.call({from: accounts[0]})
```

Comment: Also I'm assuming you're setting up `BettingInstance` correctly here. It looks a little funky to me, but it might be right.